# Elements in .join

Tags: python

I've created a grid formatted string by doing this

```
ls1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
ls2 = ["16", "17", "*", " ", "*", "*", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "*"]
ls3 = ["*", " ", "*", " ", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "*"]
ls4 = ["*", "W", " ", "F", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "*"]
ls5 = ["*", " ", "F", "W", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "*"]
ls6 = ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "Y", "*", "*"]

ls = []
ls.append(ls1)
ls.append(ls2)
ls.append(ls3)
ls.append(ls4)
ls.append(ls5)
ls.append(ls6)

grid_string = ""
for sublist in ls:
    grid_string += "".join(sublist)+ "\n"
```

and now I want to replace elements of `grid_string` with new strings but I'm not sure how elements are counted in this grid like format. So I've made the first row (`ls1`) integers in ascending order and two integers in the second row (`ls2`) to test it.

I basically did:

```
print(grid_string[3])
print(grid_string[4])
print(grid_string[5])
print(grid_string[6])
print(grid_string[7])
print(grid_string[8])
print(grid_string[9])
print(grid_string[10])
print(grid_string[11])
print(grid_string[12])
```

The output seemed logical for the first 6 prints but then the rest doesn't make much sense.

Here's what the output looked like:

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
0
1
1
1
2
1
3
```

Comment: You're concatenating numbers together in a string. The number `12` for example contains 2 characters - `1` and `2`. You can see this happening after the number 9 - it prints a 1 then a 0 (the two characters of 10) then 1 then 1 (11) etc.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: `grid_string[row][column]` is how to access individual elements of the list-of-lists you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ending output(grid_string) was the following

```
123456789101112131415
1617* ***       *
* * *         *
*W F*         *
* FW*         *
************Y**
```

Thus, the output is correct:

```
print(grid_string[3])   #4 
print(grid_string[4])   #5 
print(grid_string[5])   #6 
print(grid_string[6])   #7 
print(grid_string[7])   #8
print(grid_string[8])   #9 
print(grid_string[9])   #1 of the "10"
print(grid_string[10])  #0 of the "10" 
print(grid_string[11])  #1 of the "11" 
print(grid_string[12])  #1 of the "11"
```

When you used the string.join() method they were no longer ints and hence you were never going to get back 10 and 11

Answer (score 0):

You are joining the list of lists into a one string called `grid_string` so your end result would be something like this `123456789101112131415`

If you find `grid_string[9]`, you're essentially calling the 10th element of that string which is `1`. 
So `grid_string[9]` `grid_string[10]` together would equal `10`

```
ls1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"]
ls = []
ls.append(ls1) 

grid_string = ""    
for sublist in ls:
      grid_string += "".join(sublist)+ "\n"
      print(grid_string)

print(grid_string[9])
```

EDIT:
From your output as well, it is clear

```
4    
5    
6    
7    
8    
9

1    
0

1    
1

1    
2

1    
3
```